# How to get tablename,column names and column values seperatly from string

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I have String like below

```
 String stat="INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT(DNO, NAME, TEST_ID) VALUES (2, 'ADM', 1)";
```

How to get table name, column names and values separately from the string

Comment: This question is very unclear.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you want to **extract** table name, column names and values from that string?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the question that OP wants to extract Table Name, Column Names and Values from the provided String. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are following the same format for your `stat` String, here is how you can do it:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    String stat = "INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT(DNO, NAME, TEST_ID) VALUES (2, 'ADM', 1)";
    System.out.println("Table Name: " + stat.substring(stat.indexOf("INSERT INTO ") + 12,stat.indexOf("(")));
    System.out.println("Column Names: " + stat.substring(stat.indexOf("(") + 1,stat.indexOf(")")));
    System.out.println("Column Values: " + stat.substring(stat.indexOf("VALUES (") + 8,stat.lastIndexOf(")")));
}
```

Output:

```
Table Name: DEPARTMENT
Column Names: DNO, NAME, TEST_ID
Column Values: 2, 'ADM', 1
```

Preparing the Update statement can be bit tricky as you have to take care of whether you are setting `varchar` or `int` and do changes based on the datatype. For Example, you will always enclose `varchar` data in single quotes.

Here is an illustration on how you can prepare the Update Statement:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    String stat = "INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT(DNO, NAME, TEST_ID) VALUES (2, 'ADM', 1)";
    String tableName = stat.substring(stat.indexOf("INSERT INTO ") + 12,stat.indexOf("("));
    String columnNames = stat.substring(stat.indexOf("(") + 1,stat.indexOf(")"));
    String columnValues = stat.substring(stat.indexOf("VALUES (") + 8,stat.lastIndexOf(")"));

    /* Prepare New Values Object */
    Object[] newValues = new Object[3];
    newValues[0] = new Integer(1);
    newValues[1] = new String("foo");
    newValues[2] = new Integer(8);

    /* Extract Column Names & Appen New Values */
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("UPDATE " + tableName + " SET ");
    String[] splits = columnNames.split(", ");
    for(int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
        sb.append(newValues[i] instanceof String ? splits[i] + " = '" + newValues[i] + "', " : splits[i] + " = " + newValues[i] + ", ");
    }
    String newString = sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 2);

    /* Extract Old Values & Prepare Where Caluse */
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(" WHERE ");
    String[] splitz = columnValues.split(", ");
    for(int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
        sb.append(splits[i] + " = " + splitz[i] + " AND ");
    }
    String where = sb.substring(0, sb.length() - 5);

    /* Print Result */
    System.out.println(newString + where);
}
```

Output:

```
UPDATE DEPARTMENT SET DNO = 1, NAME = 'foo', TEST_ID = 8 WHERE DNO = 2 AND NAME = 'ADM' AND TEST_ID = 1
```

You can optimize the code more. This is just for illustration purposes.

Comment: Very user full ...Thank you

Comment: @Madhava Your Welcome! I have updated the code to make `UPDATE` Statement out of it. Hope it will be useful.

Comment: Thank you very much @user2004685

Answer (score 1):

**First approach**, split your string with regexp. Needed strings will be in array at idex `2`(table name), index `3`(col names) and index `5`(values):

```
public static void main(String[] args){        

    String stat="INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT(DNO, NAME, TEST_ID) VALUES (2, 'ADM', 1)";
    String[] strings = stat.split("[\\(\\)]|(\\b\\s\\b)");

    System.out.println(strings[2]);
    System.out.println(strings[3]);
    System.out.println(strings[5]);
}
```

Output will be:

```
DEPARTMENT
DNO, NAME, TEST_ID
2, 'ADM', 1
```

To get separate column names, you can split corresponding string again:

```
public static void main(String[] args){        

    String stat="INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT(DNO, NAME, TEST_ID) VALUES (2, 'ADM', 1)";
    String[] strings = stat.split("[\\(\\)]|(\\b\\s\\b)");

    String[] columnNames = (strings[3].split(",\\s"));
    for(String s:columnNames){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
DNO
NAME
TEST_ID
```

You can process string with values same way. This approach has less code.

**Second approach** (I would prefer) is simple regular expression:

```
publi static main(String[]args) {

    String stat="INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT(DNO, NAME, TEST_ID) VALUES (2, 'ADM', 1)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("INSERT INTO (\\w+)\\((.*)\\) VALUES \\((.*)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stat);
    if(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

Output will be:

```
DEPARTMENT
DNO, NAME, TEST_ID
2, 'ADM', 1
```

Comment: Very Useful answer ...Thank you Ken

Comment: how to formate string like  "UPDATE Department Name='ADM', Test_id=1 WHERE id=2

Comment: do it with StringBuilder class. add `update` key word and table name. when you'll get two arrays with names and values, just iterate this arrays in `for` loop, compose string (`name+"="+value`), and add it to you builder.